# pyshark error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: python

I have trouble running this python program with `pyshark`

```
import pyshark

def sort_datafile(pcap):
    cap=pyshark.FileCapture(pcap, only_summaries=True)
    print cap[0]
sort_datafile('cap_file.pcap')
```

it throws:

```
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

It has no problem using the `open()` function on the file (this file existed).

Comment: specify the full path instead

Comment: Are you sure your file can be found? You can check the current working directory using `import os print(os.getcwd())` so you may need to fully qualify the path to the pcap file

Comment: @ Rafael Cardoso full path doesn't help.

Comment: @EdChum the file can be found , I can use open() to get the file

Comment: this code works fine for me , `sort_datafile('C://Users//XYZ//Desktop//cmp-trace.pcap')`